# Product of orthogonal martingales

Tags: stochastic-analysis

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathcal F_t,P)$ be a probability space and $W(t)$ be a Brwonian Motion defined on it. Let $M(t)$ be a bounded martingale orthogonal to $W(t)$, i.e., there exists a constant $C>0$ such that $\sup_{t,\omega}|M(t)|\leq C$ and $M(t)W(t)$ is a martingale.
 For $t\geq s$, is the following ture:
$$E[(M(t)-M(s))cos(W(t)-W(s))|\mathcal F_s]=0?$$
Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you could remind us of the definition of an "orthogonal" martingale (and also explain what you mean by "bounded" since there are several notions of boundedness).

Comment: This is what I find in a book. It is said that $M\in \mathcal M_b$ which is the set of all bounded martingales and it doesnot specify the boundedness is a.s. or L^2.